# Will jailbreaking affect file system accessibility for all apps?

Tags: ios

I find that on a jailbroken device I can access `/Applications/` in a normal app from app store, although I thought due to the [sandbox](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Seatbelt) I shouldn't.

Maybe I should write an app to determine what sections of the filesystem are accessible and run it on a normal iPhone and a jailbroken one, to see if this is true.

So my question is, will jailbreaking affect file system accessibility (bypassing the sandbox) for all apps?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly  is your question?

Comment: your question is now completely different so the answer doesn't match it. Please restore the previous version and ask a new one.

Comment: I rolled back your last edit so that the existing answer makes sense. Feel free to add a new question about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to break down what you're asking.

> I find when use a jailbreak device I can access  `/Applications/`.

Yes, that's correct.  A jailbroken device can access an iOS device's root file system from a shell or any application (such as iFile).  As of iOS 8, the Applications directory has changed to `/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application`.

> But from [this](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Seatbelt), I shouldn't?

Well, not necessarily.  If the application is running as root (think iFile or Filza), you can have read and write access to any directory on the device.

> Maybe I should write a App to scan the FileSystem on a normal iPhone and a jailbreak one.

In theory, any application can ask to read or write a file to any directory.  This is frequently how jailbreak checks are done in production apps.  If the file manager does not return an error when trying to read from `/var/mobile`, then you know the application is being run as root on a jailbroken device.

Comment: I have updated my questions,  sorry for no exactly info before.